# deploying VISUAL STUDIO 2010 web application to azure cloud services

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a Web application in Visual Studio 2010 in 4.0 Framework.I want to deploy this app to azure cloud services.The application contains a local sql database as well as session variables.Can anyone please guide me on the steps to follow regarding the same.Do I have to create another database or the local database will do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a local database for an Azure web application. 
However, as mentioned in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg190738.aspx), if you want to reduce the impact that latency will have on your application, you should use an Azure SQL Database.

If you need to migrate your local database to an Azure SQL Database you can look at some of Azure SQL's [migration options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee730904.aspx).

Hope this helps!